# Integration and summation inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation

This step arise while proving infinite Hilbert matrix is bounded linear operator using Schurz test.

In my book (*Functional Analysis* by S Kesavan) it's given as follows:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(i+\frac{1}{2}+j+\frac{1}{2})\sqrt{i+\frac{1}{2}}} \leq \int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(x+j+\frac{1}{2})\sqrt{x}}. $$

I couldn't understand why this step has to be true.

I tried to convert it into integral. But one problem is it's in fraction so I couldn't any estimates.

$(i+\frac{1}{2}+j+\frac{1}{2})\sqrt{i+\frac{1}{2}}$ is not greater than ${(x+j+\frac{1}{2})\sqrt{x}}$, for all $x$. So I don't know how to  convert it into integral gives less than (we take reciprocal and then convert into integral ) It doesn't seems easy.

Comment: Hint: Write the left-hand side as the integral of an infinte sum of indicator functions.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I tried it it doesn't work that's why I asked. See the edits.  Also it was night in my country that's why I couldn't reply earlier

Comment: Is my edit sufficient.  Actually that's what I tried but I couldn't change it to integral due to the problem I mentioned.  I don't know if there is any other way. But this is the only way I know of (riemann integral into sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $a \geqslant 0$ the function
$$f_a \colon x \mapsto \frac{1}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}}$$
is convex on $(0,+\infty)$, as can easily be determined by differentiation.

For convex functions $f$ we have the inequality
$$\int_u^v f(t)\,dt \geqslant (v-u)\cdot f\biggl(\frac{u+v}{2}\biggr)$$
for all $u < v$ such that $(u,v)$ is contained in the domain of $f$. (The graph of a convex function lies above the tangents to the graph.)

Now apply this to
$$\int_i^{i+1} \frac{dx}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}}$$
for $i = 0, 1, 2, \dotsc$ with $a = j + \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Does that inequality has any name?

Comment: I'm not sure if that in particular has a name, but if you rewrite it as $$\frac{1}{v-u}\int_u^v f(t)\,dt \geqslant f\biggl(\frac{u+v}{2}\biggr)$$ it is an instance of [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality).

Comment: Its seems correct from the geometry, I checked it. But I couldn't derive it from Jensen's inequality. I took convex function f and identity

Comment: That's the right choice. For the identity you get the average $$\frac{1}{v-u}\int_u^v t\,dt = \frac{1}{v-u}\cdot \frac{t^2}{2}\Biggr\rvert_u^v = \frac{1}{v-u}\cdot \frac{v^2-u^2}{2} = \frac{(v-u)(v+u)}{2(v-u)} = \frac{v+u}{2}\,.$$ Then by Jensen's inequality $$f\biggl(\frac{u+v}{2}\biggr) = f\Biggl(\frac{1}{v-u}\int_u^v t\,dt\Biggr) \leqslant \frac{1}{v-u}\int_u^v f(t)\,dt\,.$$

Comment: Oh great. I did something silly error in computation. Thanks ,  i studied Jensen' inequality while ago but at that time i didn't thought it could be very useful (coz I'm not thinking of doing any research in anything involving in convex function) but now I understand I'm totally wrong.